# I use mikro-orm (with mongoDB) in my typescript project. How to forbid remove entity if it connected with another entity? Relation manytomany

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, mikro-orm

My entities:

```
@Entity()
export class AccessUser extends BaseEntity  {
    
     @ManyToOne(() => UserName, { onUpdateIntegrity: "no action"})
     userName: UserName;

    @ManyToMany(() => Right, a => a.accessUsers, {}/*"accessUsers")
    rights = new Collection<Right>(this);

  .....
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Right extends BaseEntity {

    @Property()
    right: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => AccessUser)
    accessUsers = new Collection<AccessUser>(this);
}

export abstract class BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: ObjectId;

  @SerializedPrimaryKey()
  id!: string;

  @Property()
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Property({ onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So I mean, that if someone wants to remove that entity - he must get an error.

Comment: What error? All you shared is an entity definition, show some code and describe what you want, how does it behave, what you expect... Entities are not cascade removed by default.